# Node.js gives two versions and gives wrong dependencies

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

This is what happens when i type the following into my Ubuntu EC2:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~$ node -v
v0.12.7
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

This shows up on my website after login:

```
Error
Unexpected token (1:66)

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:66)
```

how can i remove nodejs waste from nodejs-legacy installation? since its probably causing dependency version incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved clearing the npm cache:

```
npm cache clean
```